# recv возвращает -1

Tags: c++, c, tcp, winsock, tcpclient

Пишу TCP-сервер на C/C++ который просто принимает от клиента сообщения из файла и записывает их в другой файл (одно сообщение - одна строка в файле). Мне не известна длина сообщения и поэтому я выделяю N-oe количество байт для приема.
Пример получения сообщения:

```
while (1)
    {
        int i = 0;
        rcv[i++] = recv(client.cs, msg_num, 4, 0);
        rcv[i++] = recv(client.cs, day, 1, 0);
        rcv[i++] = recv(client.cs, month, 1, 0);
        rcv[i++] = recv(client.cs, year, 2, 0);
        rcv[i++] = recv(client.cs, AA, 2, 0);
        rcv[i++] = recv(client.cs, tel_num, tel_num_len - 1, 0);
        rcv[i++] = recv(client.cs, msg, max_msg_len, 0); // max_msg_len - const
        int ret = send(client.cs, "ok", 2, 0);
        if (ret <= 0) {
            sock_err("send", client.cs);
            return;
        }
        write_data_to_file(msg_num, day, month, year, AA, tel_num, msg, client, msg_file);
        if (strncmp("stop", msg, 4) == 0) {
            work = 0;
            return;
        } 
        memset(msg_num, 0x00, 4); memset(day, 0x00, 3); memset(month, 0x00, 3); memset(year, 0x00, 5);
        memset(AA, 0x00, 5); memset(tel_num, 0x00, tel_num_len); memset(msg, 0x00, max_msg_len);
        
    }
```

Пример отправки:

```
int net_num = htonl(message_number);
memcpy(for_send, (char*)&net_num, 4);
message_number++;
memcpy(for_send + 4, (const void*)&day, 1);
memcpy(for_send + 5, (const void*)&month, 1);
uint16_t net_year = htonl(year);
uint16_t net_AA = htonl(AA);
memcpy(for_send + 6, (const void*)&net_year, 2);
memcpy(for_send + 8, (const void*)&net_AA, 2);
memcpy(for_send + 10, phone, 12);
memcpy(for_send + 22, message, strlen(message));
int send_exit_code = send(sockfd, for_send, (1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 12 + FILE_SIZE), 0);
```

Сервер принимает только первое сообщение, а потом recv возвращает -1.
Проблема скорее всего заключается в том, что мне неизвестно количество байт, которое следует принять и сервер принимает несколько сообщений подряд. Как можно решить эту проблему? Возможно можно как то узнать длину сообщения.

Comment: Если вы с клиента отправите серверу эту самую длину сообщения, то станет возможно